# Display defects and sometimes letters disappears on my screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x11

I am experiencing a strange issue with ubuntu 14.10.

Sometimes my display defects, and is unreadable.
Moving my mouse on it or resize windows fix the display, but it's really boring.

Do you have an idea of where it could comes from ?

I'm using a core i7 laptop with 8gb ram.

Thanks

Sample of issues : 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are u facing any problem while watching movie?? or any video?? And do u have dual boot??

Comment: I have no dualboot, and I never tried any videos on this laptop

Comment: try to run a video file on it. and let me know what is ur swap memory size

Answer (score 0):

I updated my drivers using intel graphics : https://01.org/linuxgraphics/

Seems to work better !

thanks for your support & help.